# Percentage Distribution based on already present percentage

Tags: divisibility, percentages

Lets say I have 5 casino gamblers, they all account for 1500 chips. They each got 724 (48.2%), 182 (12.1%), 314 (20.9%), 72 (4.8%), and 209 (13.9%) chips respectively. If the one with 724 (48.2%) chips wanted to give away his chips to the other 4, not in 4 equal parts but respectively to the % they each got, how can I divide the 48.2% based on the % they already have? In a way that the one with 314 (20.9%) gets more, and the one with 72 (4.8%) gets less, but all tied to that initial percentage.

Edit: A comment on the downvote would be helpful.

Comment: The total each should end up with is $\frac{1500}{51.8%}\times$ initial percentage.

Comment: @RossMillikan 724+182+314+72+209 = 1501, on your formula you are using 877, but its 777, but i think your answer is still correct.

Comment: I guess I can't punch a calculator.  The approach was fine and I have fixed it.

Comment: The total % is 99.9 not 100, so the divisor in my original comment should be $51.7%$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale up their chip numbers or percentages.  The player who started with $182$ should have $\frac {182}{182+314+72+209}=\frac {182}{777}\approx 23.42\%$ of the total.  They will now have $\frac {182}{777}(724+777)\approx 352$ chips of which $170$ are from the new batch.

Comment: I get it now, the portion being given away is taken to the side, the the % for what's left is divided between the ones left and with this new % the 724 are introduced back.

Comment: Is there an equation to apply this the other way around? What if the one with 724 chips wants to take a total of 50 chips away from the others also divided by the percentage they have.

Comment: The same thing works.  Each person loses $50$ times their chips divided by the total of the four people's chips.  You just replace the $724$ with $-50$